# Azure Site to Site VPN Connectivity

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

We are going to work on Azure BizTalk Service + Service Bus Integration for one of our customer. I am exploring those two concepts. but in the mean time, I have also noticed, there is concept of "Site-To-Site" VPN connection" to establish Cloud to On-primes Network.

Can you please let me know in which scenario we need to choose Site-to-Site VPN connection?

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

You would establish a site-to-site VPN when you want to connect your Azure subscription to your on-premises data center. It could be that your BizTalk or even Service Bus infrastructure is hosted on-premises and you need to connect to it to provide functionality to your cloud service.

We would also use a S2S VPN connection when hosting virtual machines in Azure and want to connect them to networks on-premises. This would let users access these services over our own private network.